# Loading ant properties from other build files

Tags: ant, junit

I want to run an ant target 'run_junit' in my build.xml which uses the properties defined in multiple build files say junit.xml in various sub directories. I want to load all the properties from all the junit.xml files in various sub dirs before invoking this particular target.

I tried following

1. import the junit.xml files - This cannot be imported within a target. I do not want to import the files always.
2. read the junit.xml files within a target say 'load_properties' but property set in one target is not available in another target.

Can someone suggest me a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason the properties must exist in the build.xml? @Arpit pointed out, you can include them. It's likely you'll have issues with relative pathing in those properties.  check out  'special properties' under http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html
post snippets of the build files - it sounds like there may be a more optimal way to do what you want to do.  Anytime you call a target many times with different inputs (properties) you'll likely be better off with a macro.  remember ant properties aren't variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the properties in multiple targets, you would have to import them globally.

To Include another ANT file:

```
<include file="${path_to_file}/file.xml"/>
```

To Import properties from another file:

```
<property file="file_name.properties"/>
```

**Note**: These are all global definitions

Comment: I want to import the properties only for a particular target and not for every target. Secondly, the properties are defined in a build file and not properties file.

Comment: From your question - "2. read the junit.xml files within a target say 'load_properties' but property set in one target is not available in another target." That's because of a limited scope of the property defined in the target. Also, I believe you can load a build file as well.